Kolmogorov's Forward/Backward Equation
I have a question about Theorem 2.8.6 in Norris's book.(see the image I attached)

I am struggling to prove the first and third equalities in the formula marked in blue.
The notations used in the image are as follows:

$(J_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a jump time of $X$
$(Y_n:=X_{J_n})_{n\geq 0}$ is a jump process of $X$
State space is countably infinite and $q_{i}:=-q_{i,i}$

Both equalities are (intuitively) related to ''time-reversibility'' and the textbook suggests using lemma 2.8.5 ,which is related to time-reversibility. However, it can't be applied directly.
To prove the first equality, I proceeded  as follows;
$
P_i(J_n\leq t<J_{n+1}|Y_{n-1}=k,Y_n=j)\\
=\sum_{i_l}P_i(J_n\leq t<J_{n+1}|Y_1=i_1,\dots,Y_{n-2}=i_{n-2},Y_{n-1}=k,Y_n=j)P_i(Y_1=i_1,\dots,Y_{n-2}=i_{n-2}|Y_{n-1}=k,Y_n=j)\\
=\frac{q_i}{q_j}\sum_{i_l}P_j(J_n\leq t<J_{n+1}|Y_1=k,Y_2=i_{n-2}\dots,Y_{n-1}=i_{1},Y_n=i)P_i(Y_1=i_1,\dots,Y_{n-2}=i_{n-2}|Y_{n-1}=k,Y_n=j)\\
=\cdots
$
However, the latter term $P_i(Y_1=i_1,\dots,Y_{n-2}=i_{n-2}|Y_{n-1}=k,Y_n=j)$
makes it challenging to prove the equality.
Now, I am attempting to prove directly that $P_i(J_n\leq t<J_{n+1}|Y_{n-1}=k,Y_n=j)=q_k\int_{0}^{t}e^{-q_j s}P_i(J_{n-1}\leq t-s<J_n|Y_{n-1}=k)ds$  but this is
also hard.
I would appreciate for any idea or advice to prove this equation.
